# Softwindow keyboard hides the edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

i am inflating the layout using the layout inflator which had 10 editext field, when i click on the edittext soft keyboard hides the edittext if me does not inflate the layout and place in the setcontentview it workis fine. if a put requestfocus tag with inflating the layout crash the app. please find the below code and help me to resolve this.

JAVA CODE

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
setContentView(scrollView);// if i comment this and add inflatelayout SetContentView(R.layout_details) works fine.

menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);
app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, null);//
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change an attribute in your manifest (for your Activity) to handle this.  Put this line in your AndroidManifest.xml (within the tag you use to define your Activity)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: that did not made any luck to me, but if me does not inflate using inflator it works well.